# Allow rails-bootstrap-form collection to accept enumerize values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, enumerize

I am trying to drop in enum values setup with the ['Enumerize'](https://rubygems.org/gems/enumerize) gem into the radio collection select field on a [rails-bootstrap-form](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms).

An example is shown how to do this with an ActiveRecord collection. How should I modify the example

`<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :skill_level, Skill.all, :id, :name %>`

So that it can accept an enum that is setup on my model

`<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :level %>`

skill.rb

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :level, in: [:good, :ok, :bad ]
end
```

The [Enumerize documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/enumerize/0.11.0) says

> SimpleForm
>
> If you are using SimpleForm gem you don't need to specify input type
>   (:select by default) and collection:
>
> ```
> <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
>
>   <%= f.input :sex %>
>
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> and if you want it as radio buttons:
>
> ```
> <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
>
>   <%= f.input :sex, :as => :radio_buttons %>
>
>  <% end %>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using simple-form, then the documentation says all you need to do is this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @skill do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :level %>

<% end %>
```

If you're using rails-bootstrap-form, the documentation shows how to use `collection_radio_buttons` with Rails's built-in enum functionality, which you aren't using. So I believe you would need to pass in the `Skill.level.options` call as the collection values, but the `:level` method for (as the `method`, `value_method`, and `text_method` arguments):

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @skill do |f| %>

  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :level, Skill.level.options, :level, :level %>

<% end %>
```